# Mystery Impatiens ID

Tags: identification, flowers

[image: impatiens]

These just sprouted at the base of my oak tree. I don’t know how they got there, but I am letting them get established.

Based on the blossoms I would say they’re impatiens, but the shape of the leaves are throwing me off.

Would anyone know what variety this would be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an *Impatiens*; this is *Catharanthus roseus*, Madagascar Periwinkle. Native to Madagascar and widely cultivated throughout the tropics & sub-tropics. Also naturalised in many regions. Flower colour varies from white through various shades of pink.

http://keys.trin.org.au/key-server/data/0e0f0504-0103-430d-8004-060d07080d04/media/Html/taxon/Catharanthus_roseus.htm

http://powo.science.kew.org/taxon/urn:lsid:ipni.org:names:77880-1

http://keys.lucidcentral.org/keys/v3/eafrinet/weeds/key/weeds/Media/Html/Catharanthus_roseus_%28Madagascar_Periwinkle%29.htm

Comment: Good job Ben.  I just found it and got all excited only to find you had already been there done that, grins!

Comment: Thanks for the ID. I am still wondering how it got there.